# filter observable collection in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

I am developing an application in C# WPF and I am using EF6.0 framework for data. I am little confused on what would be the best way to filter an observable collection or show distinct values of a particular property. I tried doing it with this code but didn't get success. This is the method which tries to filter unique SW versions `public void getuniquesw()`. I checked Iequality comparable method but couldn't understand it. What will be the easiest way to do filtering/Distinct values.

```
public List<CREntity> crentities
{
    get;
    set;
}

// Obeservable collection property for access
private ObservableCollection<CREntity> _CRmappings2 = new ObservableCollection<CREntity>();
public ObservableCollection<CREntity> CRmappings2
{
    get { return _CRmappings2; }
    set
    {
        _CRmappings2 = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CRmappings2");
    }
}

public void UpdatePopList()
{
    CRmappings2 = new ObservableCollection<CREntity>(crentities.Where(p => p.MU_Identifier == selectmu.ToString()).ToList()); 
}

public void getuniquesw()
{

    CRmappings2 = new ObservableCollection<CREntity>(crentities.Select(p=>p.SW_Version).Distinct());
}
```

Definition of Entity Class

```
using DataModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BusinessEntities
{
    public class CREntity
    {
        public long C_ID { get; set; }
        public string LogName { get; set; }
        public string xSCR_BUG { get; set; }
        public string RequestType { get; set; }
        public string MU_Type { get; set; }
        public long CPC2_OBD_1Byte { get; set; }
        public long INS_OBD_1Byte { get; set; }
        public string MU_Identifier { get; set; }
        public string Old_MU { get; set; }
        public int? SPN { get; set; }
        public int? FMI { get; set; }
        public string Triggers { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string SW_Version { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Create_Date { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Upd_Date { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Fault_Details> FaultDetails { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know that there is a single clear problem here that anybody can help you with. Honestly, it seems like you have a fundamental misunderstand of a few concepts. It's not clear that you understand the problem that `ObservableCollection` is meant to solve based on the way you are using it. I'm not sure you completely understand types based on your implementation of `getuniquesw`. And I'm not sure how you think 'Iequality comparable method' fits into this. I think you need to step back and figure out how to tackle each issue one at a time. I'm sorry I cannot offer more help.

Comment: @JasonBoyd Thank you, I will check more on types based implementation.

Comment: @mm8 I have added the definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<CREntity>`:

```
public class CREntityComparer : IEqualityComparer<CREntity>
{
    public bool Equals(CREntity x, CREntity y)
    {
        if (x != null && y != null && x.C_ID.Equals(y.C_ID))
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CREntity obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return -1;

        return obj.C_ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

...and pass an instance of this one to the `Distinct()` method:

```
public void getuniquesw()
{
    CRmappings2 = new ObservableCollection<CREntity>(crentities.Select(p => p.SW_Version).Distinct(new CREntityComparer()));
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your help, This works great. So i should always use Iequalitycomparer if we are using the observable collection, are there any other different ways to filter also ?

Comment: There are different ways to do almost everything. But in this case, you need to define when two CREntity objects are considered to be equal.

Comment: Yes, Now my reputation touched15 and now i can upvote :)